# Ruby on Rails attr_accessible and scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have recently started building an application in rails (3.0.5).  Just to get things moving, I scaffolded one of my models (say, User).  Now, the model this creates is a completely bare extension of `ActiveRecord::Base`, however the controller makes use of `User.create(params[:user])` etc. implying `attr_accessible` is being set.

Some time later (now), after some changes, I'm getting warnings about protected fields in mass assignments, and none of these methods are working!  Can anyone help me figure out why this is and why rails would scaffold something that shouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffolding and attr_accessible are two completely different things.

When you specify an attribute as accessible, you say that when you try to mass assign(like save) your model, ONLY the accessible values will be updated. So, if you have the username field as accessible and you try to change the password field, the latter will not change and you will get a warning.

Scaffolding on the other hand, is just a quick way to get a RESTful resource up and running fast.

There is really no connection to the two ideas.

Comment: Thanks I think I figured it out.  I guess the default setting for `attr_accessible` is all the fields in the table.  However when I called `attr_accessible` to allow 'virtual' fields to work with `create` etc. it overrode this initial configuration, leaving only the properties I defined as accessible, accessible.

Comment: there is no default. You either use it for some fields or not. If not, all fields can be massively updated. If yes, even one accessible field means that the others cannot be massively update. More on the subject : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html